# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.' - C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an information management desktop app using C# on Visual Studio, however, whenever I try to delete or search a member, I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'
```

I can't really find that ")", that the error gives, I kept on looking for answers here and there, unfortunately couldn't find any, Not to mention, when I add new members it works perfectly, but only when I click delete or search for a member, the error shows up... Any help would be appreciated..

Screenshot:
[image]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Rig_Crew_Management
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ClearUp()
        {
            NameTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            GenderTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            CompanyTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            JobTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            PhoneTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            NationalityTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            DepartmentTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            AccommodationTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            RoomTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            ShiftTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-SLAB57U;Initial Catalog=crewDB;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CrewTable values (@Name, @Gender, @Company, @JobTitle, @PhoneNumber, @Department, @Nationality, @Accommodation, @RoomNumber, @Shift)", con);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(IDTextBox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NameTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", GenderTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", CompanyTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", JobTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", PhoneTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", DepartmentTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", NationalityTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accommodation",AccommodationTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNumber", RoomTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shift", ShiftTextBox.Text);


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Member Added Successfully!");
            ClearUp();
            
        }

        
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NameTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            GenderTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            CompanyTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            JobTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            PhoneTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            NationalityTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            DepartmentTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            AccommodationTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            RoomTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            ShiftTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            
        }

        private void AccommodationTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void NationalityTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void DepartmentTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void RoomTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ShiftTextBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void GenderTextBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PhoneTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void JobTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CompanyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void NameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void IDTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-SLAB57U;Initial Catalog=crewDB;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update CrewTable set Name=@Name, Gender=@Gender, Company=@Company, JobTitle=@JobTitle, PhoneNumber=@PhoneNumber, Department=@Department, Nationality=@Nationality, Accommodation=@Accommodation, RoomNumber=@RoomNumber, Shift=@Shift Where ID = @ID)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NameTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", GenderTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", CompanyTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", JobTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", PhoneTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", DepartmentTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", NationalityTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accommodation", AccommodationTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNumber", RoomTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shift", ShiftTextBox.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Member Info Updated Successfully.");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-SLAB57U;Initial Catalog=crewDB;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete CrewTable Where ID = @ID)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(IDTextBox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NameTextBox.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Member Deleted Successfully.");
        }

        private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var myForm = new Search();
            //myForm.Show();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-SLAB57U;Initial Catalog=crewDB;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from CrewTable Where Name = @Name)", con);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(IDTextBox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NameTextBox.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"Select * from CrewTable Where Name = @Name)"` - what's that `)` doing there?

Comment: In `button3_Click` method and `SearchButton_Click`, your update script ends with ')' character but doesn't have an opening one (as you don't need one). Just remove the bracket.

Comment: omg how did I not see that, thank you guys appreciate it a lot, @500-InternalServerError and Adrian

Comment: Thank you guys, appreciate it a lot. Adrian and @500-InternalServerError

Comment: You might also consider using `using` on disposable things, and reading up on why many people consider the existence of `AddWithValue` a design flaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra `)` in end of delete and search command

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete CrewTable Where ID = @ID", con);
```

do same in search.

and

Why you are sending extra parameter in delete `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NameTextBox.Text);`